# Jqplot dataRenderer using JSON-P data not plotting graph

Tags: jquery, jsonp, jqplot

In my ASP.NET MVC5 application, I have a few graphs for which I use JQPLOT and JSON-P, since I am requesting data from a cross domain source.

So my view has all the required includes files. And I am able to retrieve the data from the remote server. However the problem is plotting.

I have read a few links on STACK_OVERFLOW which talk about handling JSON data, but I havent seen anything for JSON-P (and I am almost certain that JSON-P response contains the callback information as well).

Hence I think this question is non-existant on SO, if someone can find it, please point me to it. If not please help.

View:

```
<div id="chartdiv"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ajaxDataRenderer = function (url, plot, options) {
        var ret = null;
        $.ajax({
            // have to use synchronous here, else the function will return before the data is fetched
            async: false,
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            crossDomain: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                alert('success:' + data + ':');
                ret = data;
                $('#instructions').show();
            },
            error: function () {
                $('#error').show();
                $('#chartdiv').hide();
            }
        });
        $('#loading').hide();
        return ret;
    };
    var jsonurl = "http://10.199.108.119:3000/projects/jsonp/@Model.project_id";
    var chartdiv = $.jqplot('chartdiv', jsonurl, {
        dataRenderer: ajaxDataRenderer,
        dataRendererOptions: {
            unusedOptionalUrl: jsonurl
        },
        series: [{
            label: 'Scope',
            color: '#9BBB59',
            markerOptions: {
                show: false
            }
        },
        {
            label: 'Completed Hours',
            color: '#4F81BD',
            lineWidth: 5,
            markerOptions: {
                show: false
            }
        },
        {
            label: 'Milestones',
            showLine: false,
            markerOptions: {
                style: 'x',
                color: '#8F0000',
                size: 12
            },
            pointLabels: {
                show: true,
                location: 'n',
                ypadding: 6,
                labelsFromSeries: true,
                edgeTolerance: -100,
            },
        },
        {
            label: 'Builds',
            showLine: false,
            markerOptions: {
                style: 'diamond',
                color: '#00008F',
                size: 12
            },
            pointLabels: {
                show: true,
                location: 'n',
                ypadding: 8
            },
        }],
        axesDefaults: {
            labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
        },
        defaultAxisStart: 0,
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer
            },
            yaxis: {
                label: "Effort (hours)",
                min: 0
            },
        },
        legend: {
            show: true,
            renderer: $.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer,
            location: 'ne',
            placement: 'outsideGrid',
        },
        highlighter: {
            show: true,
            sizeAdjust: 7.5,
            tooltipAxes: 'y'
        },
        cursor: {
            show: true,
            zoom: true,
            showTooltip: false
        }
    });
});
```

I am currently using Chrome DeveloperTools to debug the data received.
The data returned from the server looks like this:

`jQuery21009413928152061999_1409095444713([[['2014-08-22 12:00AM', 118], ['2014-08-21 12:00AM', 126], ['2014-08-26 12:00AM', 118], ['2014-08-15 12:00AM', 148], ['2014-08-20 12:00AM', 129], ['2014-08-25 12:00AM', 118], ['2014-08-14 12:00AM', 148], ['2014-08-13 12:00AM', 148], ['2014-08-18 12:00AM', 145]], [['2014-08-22 12:00AM', 50], ['2014-08-21 12:00AM', 50], ['2014-08-26 12:00AM', 50], ['2014-08-15 12:00AM', 14], ['2014-08-20 12:00AM', 41], ['2014-08-25 12:00AM', 50], ['2014-08-14 12:00AM', 14], ['2014-08-13 12:00AM', 8], ['2014-08-18 12:00AM', 21]], [['2014-10-10 12:00AM', 118, 'Round 3 Software Delivery'], ['2014-08-15 12:00AM', 148, 'Round 2 WR Delivery']], [['2014-09-03 12:00AM', 0, 'Build Sprint 26'], ['2014-09-12 12:00AM', 0, 'Build Sprint 28']]])`

JQPLOT doesn't render the data. What am I doing wrong?

How do I convert this JSON-P data to a format that is acceptable by JQPLOT. I have seen a lot of other examples to convert this to some kind of array, but the data here is a lot more complicated with 4 sets of values. And it also seems to be in the correct acceptable format, anyway except for the JSON-P callback header.

Please advise.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The Problem:

JSONP requests cannot be made synchronous (i.e. `async: false` is getting ignored).  Straight from the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> *Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation.*

### The Reason:

As a result, the code you presented will initialize `ret` to null, then kick off the (forced asynchronous) ajax request, and then immediately return the null `ret` value.  Some time later, the ajax request will finish and the success function will update `ret` to contain `data` but because execution has already returned from ajaxDataRenderer `data` never makes it to jqPlot.

### The Fix:

To correct the problem, start the ajax request on document load and instantiate the jqPlot object inside of the `success` function of the ajax request.

```
var burndown;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://10.199.108.119:3000/projects/jsonp/@Model.project_id",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        crossDomain: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            burndown = $.jqplot('chartdiv', data, {
                // jqPlot configuration settings go here (not specific to this example)
            });
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error!");
        }
    });
});
```